# UITableView selection that creates different NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I'm creating an app that has two view controllers both with tableviews. The first controller you select a player and the second one you select a position. Once you select a player it takes you to the second view controller to select a position.

Here are my options in the second table view:

```
self.positions = @[@"1 - Prop",@"2 - Hooker",@"3 - Prop",@"4 - Second row",
@"5 - Second     row",@"6 - Blind side flanker",@"7 - Open side flanker", @"8 - No.8",
@"9 - Scrum half",@"10 -     Outside half",@"11 - Wing",@"12 - Inside centre", 
@"13 - Outside centre",@"14 - Wing",@"15 -     Fullback"];
```

Below is my code for selecting a position in the second view.I pass the players id across and its temporarily stored in textfield2. As you can see, no matter what option you select it will save the playerid under the key "1-prop". How do I get this to change so that each of the 15 potential postition has its own userdefault?

e.g if they select"2 - Hooker" it will save the players details under a NSUserDefaults called"2-Hooker"

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString * valueToSave = self.textField2.text;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:@"1 - Prop"];
    NSString *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"1 - Prop"];
    self.testLabel.text = savedValue;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:[self.positions objectAtIndexPath:[indexPath row];
And same change for "savedValue".

Comment: thanks a lot tried it out but got an error but found out just needed to change it to : [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:valueToSave forKey:self.positions[indexPath.row]]; ... thanks so much

Comment: The error was expressed by XCode not on run time, right? It's because I forgot to close 2 bracklets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution consists in using the `NSArray positions` (for the `key`) and in `NSIndexPath` given by the delegate method `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

The key to use is: `[self.positions objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]` or `self.position[[indexPath row]]` with the *short-hand* style.